# (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443

Tags: apache, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

What I am trying to do is direct my website on an Amazon EC2 Instance so that I am able to open on an HTTPS protocol. My site was running before but with a warning that it did not have a valid certificate, using this link example  https://my.site.name.edu but now I get a "Webpage is not Available" prompt when I try to visit the site.

Please note that I have:

Installed Drupal for this testing site on a Linux server using Apache

My EC2 Instance attached to an Elastic IP

Used the steps in this guide: [Creating, Uploading, and Deleting Server Certificates](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/InstallCert.html)

Valid CA signed Apache certificates

An openssl-1.0.1f file installed in /home/ec2-user folder

Used this link to create the Virtual Host: http://ananthakrishnanravi.wordpress.com/2012/04/15/configuring-ssl-and-https-for-your-website-amazon-ec2/

**Below is when the error occurred, while trying to solve the HTTPS access issue**

I tried to change the ssl.conf file in this link to see if it would solve the problem: [Setup an SSL certificate on an EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115322/setup-an-ssl-certificate-on-an-ec2-instance)

I copied a new ssl.conf file, commented the old SSLCertificateKeyFile, SSLCertificateFile and SSLCertificateChainFile. I then pasted the copied, modified file into the directory after I coded the first four lines like this:

```
<VirtualHost 00.00.00.00:443>
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/ec2-user/castestingapache/privatekey.pem
  SSLCertificateFile /home/ec2-user/castestingapache/my_site_name_edu.pem 
  SSLCertificateChainFile /home/ec2-user/castestingapache/my_site_name_edu_interm.crt
```

But when I restarted Apache:

```
service httpd restart
```

I received this error message:

```
Stopping httpd:                                            [FAILED]
Starting httpd: [Wed May 21 14:44:31 2014] [warn] module ssl_module is already loaded,     skipping
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443
                                                       [  OK  ]
```

My httpd.conf is set up like this:

```
<VirtualHost 00.00.00.00:443>    #Same as the IP in the ssl.conf#
ServerAdmin ec2-user@ec2-00-00-00-00.compute.amazonaws.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName https://my.site.name.edu
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
# ErrorLog logs/errorlogs
# CustomLog logs/custom
SSLCertificateFile /home/ec2-user/castestingapache/my_site_name_edu.pem 
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/ec2-user/castestingapache/privatekey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /home/ec2-user/castestingapache/my_site_name_edu_interm.crt
# SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/bundle.txt 
SetEnvIf User-Agent “.*MSIE.*” nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
# CustomLog /usr/local/apache/logs/ssl_request_log \
# “%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \”%r\” %b”
</VirtualHost>
```

**EDIT:** I tried reverting back to the old ssl.conf but when I try to restart Apache it gives me the same error. **THIS PROBLEM HAS BEEN SOLVED** *I had to delete one of the ssl.conf even though I had renamed it...*

**Update** I have added this line onto the httpd.conf file:

```
NameVirtualHost 00.00.00.00:443
```

I believe the problem is that my certificates are not pointing to this IP address.

**Update** I have just ran the certificate installation checker test here http://ssltool.com/?action=sslCheckOpenSSL and this is what I got: 
[image]

Note: IP 12-34-56-78 is my private IP address on my AWS EC2 Instance.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Seems something is already using port 443. Is there another virtualhost that may be using the same port, or have you been previously running another web server?

Comment: We do have multiple sites running on AWS EC2 Instance with Inbound Rule 443 Port Range open. Does that help?

Comment: I'm sorry! I have just deleted the old ssl.conf and now my site is back up... But I am still trying to solve the invalid SSL Certificate error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh.... the answer was in this link the whole time...

[Setup an SSL certificate on an EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115322/setup-an-ssl-certificate-on-an-ec2-instance)

This line in the ssl.conf:

```
<VirtualHost 00.000.000.00:443>
```

Had to be changed to:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
```

Add the rest:

```
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/mydomain_com.key
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/mydomain_com.crt
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/mydomain_com.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>
```

And voilah! Your HTTPS: link should work...